# How is postgis treating coordinates sent with different SRID

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, postgis, srid

I am running a django application and I am using the PostGis extension for my db. I am trying to understand better what happens under the hood when I send coordinates, especially because I am working with different coordinate systems which translate to different SRIDs. My question is threefold:

1. Is django/postgis handling the transformation when creating a Point or Polygon in the DB.
2. Can I query it back using a different SRID
3. Is it advisable to use the default SRID=4326

Let's say I have a model like this (note I am setting the standard SRID=4326):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
    )
    point = models.PointField(
        srid=4326,
    )
    polygon = models.PolygonField(
        srid=4326,
    )
```

1. Now I am sending different coordinates and polygons with different SRIDS.

I am reading here in the django docs that:

> Moreover, if the GEOSGeometry is in a different coordinate system (has a different SRID value) than that of the field, then it will be implicitly transformed into the SRID of the model’s field, using the spatial database’s transform procedure

So if I understand this correctly, this mean that when I am sending an API request like this:

```
data = {
   "name": "name"
   "point": "SRID=2345;POLYGON ((12.223242267 280.123144553))"
   "polygon": "SRID=5432;POLYGON ((133.2345662 214.1429138285, 123.324244572 173.755820912250072))"

}

response = requests.request("post", url=url, data=data)
```

Both - the polygon and the point -  will correctly be transformed into SRID=4326??

EDIT:

When I send a point with `SRID=25832;POINT (11.061859 49.460983)` I get `'SRID=4326;POINT (11.061859 49.460983)'` from the DB. When I send a polygon with `'SRID=25832;POLYGON ((123.2796155732267 284.1831980485285, ' '127.9249715130572 273.7782091450072, 142.2351651215613 ' '280.3825718937042, 137.558146278483 290.279508688337, ' '123.2796155732267 284.1831980485285))'` I get a polygon `'SRID=4326;POLYGON ((4.512360573651161 0.002563158966576373, ' '4.512402191765552 0.002469312460126783, 4.512530396754145 ' '0.002528880231016955, 4.512488494972807 0.00261814442892858, ' '4.512360573651161 0.002563158966576373))'` from the DB

2. Can I query it back using a different SRID

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to query the same points back to their original SRID. Is this even possible?

3. And lastly I am working mostly with coordinates in Europe but I also might have to include sporadically coordinates from all over the world too. Is `SRID=4326` a good standard to use?

Thanks a lot for all the help in advance. Really appreciated.

Comment: Hi there! Since I know nothing about djang I will leave a comment from a GIS perspective: To your question: "Both - the polygon and the point - will correctly be transformed into SRID=4326??" have you tried the script and checked in PostgreSQL in which SRS the coordinates are stored? Try using ST_AsEWKT. And "Can I query it back using a different SRID": yes, you can use ST_Transform for that matter. "Is it advisable to use the default SRID=4326" WGS84 is the most used SRS, so I'd tend to say yes, but it all depends on your use case. Perhaps the area you're covering demands a different SRS

Comment: Thanks @JimJones. Yes I have checked and it saves with `SRID4326`. But I don't know if it also gets converted correctly. For instance if I send a point POINT (11.061859 49.460983) I get the same values from the DB with different SRID. When I send a polygon I get different values with different SRID (I edited my question)

Comment: It is highly unlikely that two reference systems end up with the same coordinates for the same place after a transformation, so I believe your suspicion might be well justified: the SRS is simply being changed but no transformation is being performed.  Have you tried plotting them to a map to see if they still correspond to the same place, e.g. using the Geometry Viewer of pgAdmin IV?

Comment: ahhhh but wait, sorry... The point was not correctly written to the database.... Now it does actually give me a different value. Now I am very sure it is actually transforming correctly (if you want to include that in your answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transforming SRS of geometries is much more than just changing their SRID. So, if for some reason after a transformation the coordinates return with exactly the same values, there was most probably no transformation at all.

This example uses [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) to transform a geometry from `25832` to `4326`. See the results yourself:

```
WITH j (geom) AS (
 VALUES('SRID=25832;POINT (11.061 49.463)'::geometry))
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom),ST_AsEWKT(ST_Transform(geom,4326)) FROM j;

 

       st_asewkt            |                      st_asewkt                       
---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 SRID=25832;POINT(11.061 49.463) | SRID=4326;POINT(4.511355210946569 0.000446125446657)
(1 Zeile)
```

- The Polygon transformation in your question is btw correct.

Make sure that django is really storing the values you mentioned. Send a `25832` geometry and directly check the SRS in the database. If you're only checking using django, it might be that it is transforming the coordinates back again in the requests, which might explain you not seeing any difference.

To your question:

> Is SRID=4326 a good standard to use?

WGS84 is the most used SRS worldwide, so I'd tend to say yes, but it all depends on your use case. If you're uncertain of which SRS to use, it might indicate that your use case does not impose any constraint to it. So, stick to WGS84 but keep in mind that you don't mix different SRS in your application. Btw: if you try to store geometries in multiple SRS in the same table, PostgreSQL will raise an exception ;)

Further reading: [`ST_AsEWKT`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html), [`WGS84`](https://georepository.com/crs_4326/WGS-84.html)

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation and effort. As mentioned I wrote the coordinates incorrectly to the DB for the POINT. Thus it is doing the conversion correctly. Querying back I'll do with your mentioned `ST_Transform`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm not big expert at GIS (I have created just a few small things in Django and GIS), but...
In this documentaion about GeoDjango: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#automatic-spatial-transformations . According to it:

> When doing spatial queries, GeoDjango automatically transforms geometries if they’re in a different coordinate system. ...

Try in console (`./manage.py shell`):

```
from <yourapp>.models import MyModel
obj1 = MyModel.objects.all().first()
print(obj1)
print(obj1.point)
print(dir(obj1.point))
print(obj1.point.srid)
```

--edit--
You can manually test converting between SRID similary to this page: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94640/geodjango-transform-not-working

```
obj1.point.transform(<new-srid>)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Well, `print(obj1.point.srid)` gives me the SRID 4326. But I still am not 100% sure if this is transformed correctly. I assume so though. I am just confused because as I explain in my edit the POINT is returning different values whereas the POLYGON returns divergent values before and after creation....