# how to find ou lat long with 2KM radius using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a postgres table with lat-long values stored as point (Geometric data type). I am interested to query all rows with 2km radius for the given lat-long values. Also, I am expecting for a suitable datatype for this, currently I stored these values as POINT. But on some investigation, I found to use POLYGON here. But even though I couldn't able to achieve the results what expected.

Can any one point me the exact query with suitable GTS functions to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html
example explanation:

```
SELECT name
FROM nyc_streets
WHERE ST_DWithin(
        geom,
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(583571 4506714)',26918),
        10
      );
```

- The first "geom" refer to the column name in nyc_streets.
- ST_GeomFromText: transform text to geom. 26918 is srid.
- 10 : 10 meters.

Comment: Your understanding of `ST_GeomFromText` is wrong. It does **not** transform a geometry, but it simply creates a geometry from a WKT literal and sets a SRS if provided. Check it yourself: `SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)',26918))` <- according to your logic it should transform the geometry, but in the end all you have is **exactly the same coordinate** with a different (wrong!) SRS.

Comment: @JimJones You are right.  `SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)',26918))` srid will be 26918.

Comment: Yes, and it's a big issue. The coordinates that are originally `WGS84` will be invalid if seen as `EPSG:26918`.

Answer (score 0):

To query geometries within a certain radius you might wanna use [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). In order to use it with metres you have to either use a SRS that has metre as unit, such as [`EPSG:26918`](https://epsg.io/26918), or use `geography` instead of `geometry`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(1,2)::geography, -- 1=long / 2=lat
                 geom::geography, -- casting the 'geometry' to 'geography'
                 2000); -- 2km radius
```

In case you're dealing with different geometry types, such as `polygon` or `linestring`, you might wanna use `ST_GeogFromText` instead of `ST_MakePoint`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(1 2)'),
                 geom::geography,2000); 

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE  ST_DWithin(ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1))'),
                  geom::geography,2000);
```

Keep in mind that transforming a geometry is much more than just change its SRID - check [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html).

Further reading

- [`Getting all Buildings in range of 5 miles from specified coordinates`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388)
- [`How is postgis treating coordinates sent with different SRID`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66241981/2275388)